# Will plagiarism software find my drafts in Overleaf?

Tags: mathematics, thesis, plagiarism, latex

I am a Ph.D. student in mathematics and soon will start writing a thesis on my published papers. I think Overleaf (online cloud) would be more flexible to write the thesis instead my TeXstudio editor. Our university library checks the thesis through Urkund plagiarism software. I have no worry on that part because my papers are already published and properly checked by the library.

Before my question, I just want to mention that if one replaces an article in arXiv with a revised version, then Urkund or any other plagiarism software also counts the previous version towards the similarity score, but in that case our university doesn't count the earlier version since the author is the same.

Since Overleaf is an online cloud editor, every LaTeX file will be stored digitally.

In this case, does any plagiarism software track the saved file from Overleaf?

Comment: I would advise against using overleaf for writing your PhD thesis. You we want your manuscript somewhere where you are not reliant on an internet connection to access and edit it. An offline tex editor, and using git for version control is a better option for the task at hand.

Comment: Please note that the sentence *"our university doesn't count the amount of plagiarism from the earliar version"* cannot be correct: there simply is no "plagiarism from [an] earlier version" since updating a paper on arXiv has nothing to do with plagiarism. Your university simply acknowledges this fact rather than not counting some kind of plagiarism.

Comment: @JochenGlueck, well thanks. What is advice regarding overleaf and phd thesis ?

Comment: @learner: I think Coder's answer already contains all the relevant advice.

Comment: @TimRias - having multiple backups in multiple separate physical places (i.e. not all on your laptop or at your house - different cloud providers are likely separate physical places) is the way to go, whether using version control or not.

Comment: @JochenGlueck  Presumably they mean "similarity score" rather than "plagiarism" per se.  I've seen plenty of cases where a piece of student work got a very high Turnitin similarity score, but it turned out that the main source to which there was high similarity was the student's own previous draft of the same assignment, which had somehow got into the Turnitin database - having established that, I could configure Turnitin to exclude that source from its calculation.

Comment: If your university is getting hung up on the fact that your PhD work is already published (by you!), I'd say the mechanics of Overleaf are the least of your problems...

Comment: @DanielHatton, yes, exactly that is what I meant.

Comment: @JonCuster - I remember, in years past, seeing sad - even pathetic - signs pasted on telephone poles in several different college towns - people begging someone who broke into their car or stole the entire thing to please _please_  **please** just return _the manuscript of their thesis_ - the only copy in existence, you can keep the rest, just **_please_** ....  It would be a shame if, in this digital age, people didn't _back up their work_ when it is _so easy to do so_.

Comment: There are a couple of ways to sync Overleaf with other cloud services (which in turn are easier to sync to your local system), but unfortunately they all seem to be premium options now ... sigh ... https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Working_Offline_in_Overleaf  . Less conveniently, you can also export zip files of the project regularly (e.g. daily): https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Exporting_your_work_from_Overleaf . You can unpack these and work on them locally if Overleaf craps out on you (although syncing your work back to Overleaf could be a pain ...)

Comment: @davidbak - even now, may people think a second copy on their laptop is a "backup" somehow. You would think that a Google drive and just emailing yourself copies would readily come to mind, but...

Comment: The chance of Overleaf servers going down or anything happening to them before you finish your PhD thesis is vanishingly small.

Comment: @TimRias You can use Overleaf and just sync to GitHub/Dropbox and still be able to work offline if needed.

Comment: @TimRias Overleaf is completely compatible with that workflow — including exposing its cloud storage as a Git repo (which you can sync elsewhere if you like). If you use it sensibly it helps with data redundancy, not hinders :)

Comment: @JonCuster But setting your account on github and use git for version control will serve as the backup repository and version control. The bonus is, when connection fails, you can still work and update the cloud version later. But note that git si very efficient with plain text but sucks with any other data.

Comment: @Crowley Then `.gitignore` non-text.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo True. But if you NEED to track non-text, typically graphs and schemes, then you should look elsewhere. Either use TikZ to compile the graphics form text, or use other version control tool for it.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Overleaf doesn’t make any documents public. ArXiv hosts preprints, whereas Overleaf is an online LaTeX editor where the files owned by a user are secure and private, equivalent to how nobody from outside can access your emails in Gmail.

Comment: Are you sure nobody from outside has access to your emails in Gmail?

Comment: Ha ha. Let’s not go there @MaartenBuis We live in a strange world.

Answer (score 71):

*I'm Tom and I work for Overleaf as a Support Manager.*

Overleaf does not make any data you have on Overleaf public, unless you explicitly choose so by enabling link-sharing and sharing the link on the internet. So unless you do that (or expose your project e.g. by sharing it with untrusted people), the project cannot be scanned by a 3rd party.

So in short: You are safe preparing your projects on Overleaf :)

Comment: Thank you so much for the information

Comment: Overleaf is an outstanding platform that makes a researcher’s  life so simple and easy. You guys deserve a huge respect. In fact, I have acknowledged Overleaf in my thesis too.

Comment: @Coder That's great to hear! Btw, I didn't mean to steal the attention from your answer as it's 100% correct, I just thought that an authoritative response might be useful in this case!

Comment: Haha. I also liked an answer from OL. I have +1-ed it myself :-)